# How to use random number generator with if statements

Tags: java, random, numbers

so I am making a text-based game, and I want to use a random number generator to say if the random number that it generates is 3, that it will say that a certain monster has appeared. For some reason it is having trouble allowing me to do an if statement for the random number. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mainClass 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String username, character_type, testing_enemy;

        //Variables for spells
        double mage_fire, mage_iceblast, mage_voidray;
        double warrior_uppercut, warrior_kick, warrior_hook;
        double archer_diamond, archer_power, archer_precision;

        //variables for base stats
        int base_health, base_spell_dmg, base_attack_dmg, base_mana;

        //variable for random number generator
        int number = Integer.parseInt(testing_enemy);

        System.out.println("Welcome to Realm Of Worlds!");
        System.out.println("Enter username: ");
        username = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Realm Of Worlds " + username);
        System.out.println("Realm Of Worlds is an interactive text based game "
                + "that allows you to fight monsters and buy items and spells to get even stronger.");
        System.out.println("Would you like to be a Mage, a Warrior, or an Archer?");
        character_type = input.nextLine();


        if(character_type.equals("mage") || character_type.equals("Mage"))
        {
            System.out.println("Ok, " + username + " you are now a " + character_type + "!");

            base_health = 850;
            base_spell_dmg = 60;
            base_attack_dmg = 50;
            base_mana = 500;

            System.out.println("As a Mage, you have " + base_health + " base health, " + base_spell_dmg + " base spell damage, " + base_attack_dmg + " base attack damage, and " + base_mana + " base mana.");
            System.out.println("Your spells are Fire Blast, Ice Blast, and Void Ray.");
            System.out.println("All of your spells do Spell Damage, so focus on building Spell Damage Items");

            mage_fire = (30 + (.60*base_spell_dmg));
            mage_iceblast = (50 + (.45*base_spell_dmg));
            mage_voidray = (45 + (.55*base_spell_dmg));

            System.out.println("Would you like to use 1. Fire Blast, 2. Ice Blast, 3. Void Ray? (Just type 1, 2, or 3)");

        }


        if(character_type.equals("warrior") || character_type.equals("Warrior"))
        {
            System.out.println("Ok, " + username + " you are now a " + character_type + "!");

            base_health = 1000;
            base_spell_dmg = 20;
            base_attack_dmg = 80;
            base_mana = 300;

            System.out.println("As a Warrior, you have " + base_health + " base health, " + base_spell_dmg + " base spell damage, " + base_attack_dmg + " base attack damage, and " + base_mana + " base mana.");
            System.out.println("Your spells are Uppercut, Kick, and Hook Punch");
            System.out.println("All of your spells do Attack Damage, so focus on building Attack Damage Items");

            warrior_uppercut = (30 + (.55*base_attack_dmg));
            warrior_kick = (50 + (.45*base_attack_dmg));
            warrior_hook = (45 + (.50*base_attack_dmg));
        }

        if(character_type.equals("archer") || character_type.equals("Archer"))
        {
            System.out.println("Ok, " + username + " you are now a " + character_type + "!");

            base_health = 700;
            base_spell_dmg = 40;
            base_attack_dmg = 70;
            base_mana = 400;

            System.out.println("As an Archer, you have " + base_health + " base health, " + base_spell_dmg + " base spell damage, " + base_attack_dmg + " base attack damage, and " + base_mana + " base mana.");
            System.out.println("Your spells are Diamond Arrow, Power Shot, and Precision Eye");
            System.out.println("Also, as archer, you have a passive ability of dodging 1 in every 6 attacks from an opponent");
            System.out.println("Your spells do a combination of Spell and Attack Damaeg, so it is worth building both types of items, but more Attack Damage is done than Spell Damage");

            archer_diamond = (30 + ((.35*base_attack_dmg)+(.20*base_spell_dmg)));
            archer_power = (50 + ((.30*base_attack_dmg)+(.15*base_spell_dmg)));
            archer_precision = (45 + ((.35*base_attack_dmg)+(.15*base_spell_dmg)));
        }

        //Setting up enemy randomization
        **Random dice = new Random();

        for(int counter=1; counter<=3; counter++)
        {
            number = 1+dice.nextInt(3);

            if(number.equals(3))
            {
                System.out.println("A monster appeared!!");
            }**
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are rolling three dices, chances are high, that one of these is a three. About 75% of the time you will get at least one Monster...

Comment: Have you looked at the help center?

Comment: I know, but I am just using those numbers as a test. I want to get a monster a lot of the time on purpose

Comment: I have looked at multiple places but can't seem to find an answer

Comment: You've posted over 100 lines of code, but failed to say what the actual problem is. "For some reason it is having trouble allowing me to do an if statement for the random number" just tells us that you *have* a problem, not what the problem *is*. Please focus on making your question clearer, and provide a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. (The answer is to use ==, as Kostronor says - but you should pay attention to the art of writing a good question too.)

Comment: Sorry, I will do this in the future

Answer (score 0):

You are using equals which accepts an object. But int is no object. Try == instead.

```
if (number == 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (number == 3)` instead of `if (number.equals(3))`. Normally, `var.equals()` is for objects and strings. Comparing numerical values (integers and floating point) can be done with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take an example.

Suppose I wish to generate a number between 5-10.

```
  int max=10;
    int min=5;
    int diff=max-min;
    Random rn = new Random();
    int i = rn.nextInt(diff+1);
    i+=min;
    System.out.print("The Random Number is " + i);
```

lets understand this

nitialize max with highest value and min with the lowest value.

Now, we need to determine how many possible values can be obtained. For this example, it would be

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

So, count of this would be max-min+1.

```
i.e. 10-5+1=6
```

The random number will generate a number between 0-5.

```
i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Adding the min value to the random number would produce

```
5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

Hence we obtain the desired range.